# at what percentage of old generation GC runs?

Tags: java, performance

when I run "jmap -heap ", i get the following

[image]

If you notice, PS Old Generation is just a little over 9% used while Eden is ~4.5% used. 
At what percentage of Eden does minor GC occur? 
At what percentage of PS Old generation does the stop the world GC occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Exact percentage would vary based on algorithm you are using.

Refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/

Best solution : go to your java bin ex: java-1.8.0-oracle/bin.
and run jstat -gc -t PID 1s and see yourself when major are minor gc are getting triggered.

It will give you current memory size and GC occurrence count for all major and minor GC parameters.

refer the attachment for example.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzu12.png)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple :

Minor GC is triggered when JVM does not have space for a new Object example :Eden is getting full.
Try the command : jstat -gc -t 5000 1s see behaviors of young generation.

Regarding  *At what percentage of PS Old generation does the stop the world GC occurs?*

Even Minor GC stops application threads leading to stop the world.(but its comparatively negligible)

Stop the world event occur every time, when minor or major GC or full gc is triggered and to check when full GC will triggered. 
Major GC is cleaning the Tenured space.
Full GC is cleaning the entire Heap – both Young and Tenured spaces.

You can set flags to modify them depending on algorithm you are using for GC.

Comment: Thx for your answer. However, I'm looking to find implementation details as to at what %age JVM kicks GC. Its before 100% as JVM's GC algo itself requires some space. I'm trying to monitor heap spaces for generating alerts for a hot stdby to takeover.